# SQL Coalesce STR results in an INT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following:

```
    Select tp.PH_F pHF, COALESCE(STR(tp.pH_F), tp.pH_S) pH
     From tblprod tp
```

Note that PH_F is a float

I get the following results

```
PHF    PH
---    ---
7.256   7
7.59   8
```

Why does the STR convert int the Coalesce result in an INT? What I like happen is have it be the same value.

What I like happen is the following:

```
PHF    PH
---    ---
7.256   7.256
7.59   7.59
```

How can I have this happen with the Coalesce?

Comment: Have you tried putting STR() around tp.pH_S?

Comment: What is the desired datatype of the result? A string? Or a `decimal(n,2)` is fine?

Comment: @adam - tp.pH_S is already a string

Comment: @MartinSmith - what happens if the decimal is say .xxx s in 7.256?

Comment: What happens when? I haven't made any suggestions I am still trying to discern your requirement.  It seems from your other comments you are trying to convert it to a string and preserve all decimal places until they become all zeros? If so this will probably be quite a pain to do in SQL especially for the float datatype as it doesn't always round to decimal nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it how many decimal places you want. The STR function defaults to 0. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx

You probably want to change your code to something like:

```
Select tp.PH_F pHF, COALESCE(STR(tp.pH_F, 5, 2), tp.pH_S) pH
     From tblprod tp
```

Comment: as it is a float, we can have it be x number of digits. How do I handle this?

Comment: Try setting the decimal parameter to the max (16) and it will give you up to that many: Select tp.PH_F pHF, COALESCE(STR(tp.pH_F, 5, 16), tp.pH_S) pH From tblprod tp